# Print only a part of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written a code which prints only a part of a web page. For this I've used `<div>`.

**The code is as follows:**

```
<div id="printme">
    <table width='1000'  align="center">
    <tr><td>
    <h1> CANDIDATE DETAILS</h1>
             -----
             -----
             -----
             -----
</div>
<div id="dnt_print">
    <fieldset>
    <legend> <b>Uploads: </b></legend>
    <table width='900' align="center" >
              ----
              ----
              ----
     <td align="center">
       <input type="button" value="PRINT DETAILS" onclick="printdetails()">
     </td>
 </div>
```

**and my JS to print is as follows:**

```
function printdetails()
{
    alert("Allow Pop-ups");
    var myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    var x=document.getElementById("printme").innerHTML;
    myWindow.document.write(x);
    myWindow.print();
    myWindow.close();
}
```

But the problem is, when I click to print, the new window that pop-us displays the complete details, rather than only the `<div id="printme">--</div>`'s `innerHTML`!! Please help me

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors on the console?

Comment: NO! I can have the output! But with the complete page @imulsion

Comment: You should use CSS media rules for this.

Comment: Your div with innerHTML contains the whole table.

Comment: Add `myWindow.focus()` before printing.

Comment: Why not try reading about using @media rules. You may get the printed output as one desires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making it complex , play with the `visibility` CSS property of the element by using the value `hidden`/`visible`

Comment: I'd use `display:none`, but I second this.

Comment: (to clarify if the OP doesn't know: you can set media-specific CSS, so you would put this in a `media=print` script)

Comment: I'm tossing a -1 on this one, this is because personally I dislike answers that don't answer the question, but simply provide alternative solutions.. These kinds of answers should be comments instead.

Comment: I just wrote the answer instead of the comment, coz I thought if this ans helped OP to solved his problem that must be an answer. Sorry, if I'm wrong. You can flag this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can print specific part(s) of webpage.

It also includes how to implement css and javascript in the printout page.

Also for multiple part of pages, you can apply "< br >" tag as I implemented below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printCommission() {
    // For logo html (part 1 for print out)
    var prtContent = document.getElementById("logo");

    // This is the div I was required to include in print out (part 2 for print out)    
    var prtContent1 = document.getElementById("dashboardbody1");

    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

    // To apply css  
    WinPrint.document.write("<style> .commission td, .commission th {border-color: #CCCCCC;padding: 4px;}  .commission th {background-color: #106C9B;border-color: #CCCCCC;color: #FFFFFF;} .commission { border-collapse: collapse; color: #000000; text-align: center; } .commission td.td-noborder { border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;} .bg-grey {    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;} .bold {    font-weight: bold !important;}</style>");

    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML + "<br><br>" + prtContent1.innerHTML);

    // to apply javascript (I used it to hide buttons) 
    WinPrint.document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>" + " window.onload=function(){ document.getElementById('downloadReport').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('printout').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('imgCommission').style.display='none';}; <" + "/" + "script>");

    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
    return false;
}
```